# 2 programs that send messages to each other in Java

Tags: java

I want to make 2 programs that communicate with each other. For example, program A will wait for an integer value and program B will send an interger value there, but do it itself without showing it to the user.Or program A will wait for a boolean value named check, and program B will send true to the value named check.How can I do these in Java?

Comment: Is B the subprocess of A? If it is, you have access to its input/output streams. Otherwise you have to make a server-client like structure. You can dead about sockets [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)

Comment: Both are different projects and both are jar files